# How do I specificy the order of execution for methods in my testing?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unit-testing, junit

I have a .java file called **myTest.java** and inside of it I have two test methods (in this order created) called:

```
public void testGrabSubdevicedata(){
     // do something and assert 
}

public void testSubdevice(){
    // do something again and assert
}
```

For some reason it executes the "testSubdevice()" method first, and so there must be some sort of alphabetical method execution set. How do I turn this off so it executes in the order I placed it it?

EDIT:

This is with Eclipse Jee Neon and Maven plugin.

Comment: Unit Tests should never have dependencies or depending on an order. This means those unit tests are integration tests. Simplest to solve using TestNG which can define dependencies between tests...If you need them...

Comment: Thank for the advice, it makes more sense if there was no ordering involved. I'll definitely try to avoid this practice unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class WhateverTest {
```

This will guarantee you that JUnit runs your test in that specific order. There aren't too many such orders; but probably one that fits your needs.

But a word of warning: this is **bad** practice! Fixing execution order is something that you should only do when you have very good reasons to do so.

Finally: read about java naming style guides. Class names start UpperCase; always; even for tests.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's more reliable if there wasn't any intentional ordering unless for good reasons as you stated.